# Unable to download when source file size is zero byte

Tags: c#, chilkat

> I am using **chilkat x64 9.5.0.89** version in my C# application for dowloading file from SFTP through "downloadbyfilename" option. I have requirement to download a file with zero byte. When we try to download we get error in this version as shown below but my earlier version download the same file  without any issue. I get error from chilkat as

**--Chilkat Error**

> ChilkatLog:
> DownloadFileByName:
> DllDate: Nov 28 2021
> ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.89
> UnlockPrefix: *****(removed for security reason)
> Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
> Language: .NET 4.6 / x64 / VS2015
> VerboseLogging: 0
> SshVersion: SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_1.0.1
> SftpVersion: 3
> IdleTimeoutMs: 30000
> downloadFileByName:
> PreserveDate: 0
> fromFilePath: /Download1/1TestZero.pdf
> toFilePath: E:\Test\1TestZero.pdf
> OpenRemoteFile:
> sftpOpenFile:
> remotePath: /Download1/1TestZero.pdf
> access: readOnly
> createDisposition: openExisting
> v3Flags: 0x1
> Sent FXP_OPEN
> responseMsgType: SSH_FXP_HANDLE
> handle: 00000000
> --sftpOpenFile
> timeToOpenMs: Elapsed time: 281 millisec
> --OpenRemoteFile
> fetchRemoteFileAttributes1:
> fetchAttributes:
> filename: /Download1/1TestZero.pdf
> Using FXP_STAT
> Sent message to fetch attributes.
> Received SSH_FXP_ATTRS
> --fetchAttributes
> timeToFetchAttrMs: Elapsed time: 266 millisec
> --fetchRemoteFileAttributes1
> SFTP server did not provide remote file size.
> resumeFlag: 0
> Reading until end of file..
> soRcvBuf: 1048576
> soSndBuf: 1048576
> cryptAlgorithm: aes
> macAlgorithm: SHA-1
> compression: no
> newDownloadLoop:
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> fx_status: SSH_FX_EOF
> FXP_status_message: e
> Did nothing for 60 seconds!
> --newDownloadLoop
> sftpCloseHandle:
> handle: 00000000
> Sent FXP_CLOSE
> statusResponseFromServer:
> request: FXP_CLOSE
> statusCode: 0
> statusMessage:
> --statusResponseFromServer
> --sftpCloseHandle
> timeToCloseHandleMs: Elapsed time: 281 millisec
> Closing local output file...
> totalTimeMs: Elapsed time: 61453 millisec
> --downloadFileByName
> Failed.
> --DownloadFileByName
> --ChilkatLog

Comment: If the file is zero in size there is nothing to download. You can just create a file with the same name locally.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I also planned for similar kind of work around but before doing that just wanted to intimate Chilkat or know whether already fix available for it. Actually same version work for Uploading a zero byte file only for Download it gives error. Also earlier version works for both upload and download zero byte file. so just want to find whether there is any sub release from Chilkat for this fix.. Thanks anyway